# Observable vs Promise for single values

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, rxjs, observable

Typescript (and now also ECMAScript 2017) gives you great asynchronous tools to use in the form of async/await. However, working with Angular 4, I get the feeling that using Observables is preferred. My question is: When I have a function which returns a **single value once** (ex: confirmation modal), are there any big advantages with using observables, or would promises (async/await) be preferred/just as good? Is it not weird to use observables? Do they not represent a stream of values?

Tl;dr:

```
async showDialog(msg: string): Promise<DialogResult>
```

vs.

```
showDialog(msg: string): Observable<DialogResult>
```

Comment: *"Typescript gives you great asynchronous tools to use in the form of async/await."* So does JavaScript, now.

Comment: Well-phrased. By asking *"...are there any big advantages with using observables..."* you're asking for concrete information, not opinion. It makes good sense to default to the thing that exactly matches your use-case (Promises) and is readily composed with other one-off async results (via `await` and others) and need concrete reasons to do something else.

Comment: Apparently ECMAScript 2017 has support for this, thanks for pointing that out, will edit the question. My thoughts exactly, I recently started working with Angular, which is also when I was first introduced to RxJS. Let's see what people say. And thanks for the compliment on the phrasing!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which one you use. Promises and Observables can be freely interchanged. Have a look at this https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875

I personally find it easier to work with Observables even when you need to return just one value.

With Promises you often need to keep three properties:

```
class Whatever {
  resolve: Function;
  reject: Function;
  promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.resolve = resolve;
    this.reject = reject;
  });    

  method() {
    return this.promise;
  }

  otherMethod() {
    this.resolve();
  }
}
```

With Observables you can keep just an instance of Subject:

```
class Whatever {
  subject = new Subject();

  method() {
    return this.subject.toPromise();
  }

  otherMethod() {
    this.subject.next(...);
    this.subject.complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you don't *need* to, for a couple of reasons, not least that normally you wouldn't have a promise as an instance property; they're *operation*-specific. `method` would just return the promise and call the appropriate settlement function. But if you needed it as an instance property, it's easy enough to wrap or extend `Promise` (once, reusably) so you just keep track of one thing.

Comment: Well, in practise this is usually the easiest way to do it without creating extending the default `Promise` class.

Comment: But if you have to do this regularly, extending or wrapping Promise would be the right solution -- since you seem not to want to track three separate properties.

Comment: Yes, so basically you'll use Subjects.

Comment: No, there's a **big** semantic difference. This is the point, as raised in the question. If I'm using an API returning `Subject<any>`, that says it provides [a stream of values](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/subjects/subject/index.html), 0...n, and if I'm not misreading doesn't inherently differentiate between values and errors. `Promise<any>` says it returns exactly one value, or exactly one error, differentiating the two, and guarantees that one of those things (value or error) will happen.

Comment: That's why I'm returning `this.subject.toPromise()`. The consumer expect me to return a Promise, so I'm returning a Promise. But what's the internal implementation is up to me and that's where it's easier to use Subjects instead of Promises.

Comment: Fair enough. I still don't see any reason the Promise/Subject needs to live outside `method`, I've literally never had to hold a promise as an instance property. But whatever, it's true `method`'s signature provides the semantics.

Comment: @martin has a point, and in my case, I actually had to save the resolve function as an instance variable. The class is a modal, which only returns after user input (which calls a separate function). However, I'm not sure that I agree with using ```.toPromise();``` just to combine two variables into one. Seems overkill to import an entire library for such a small convenience. However, I'm still struggling with when to use ```.toPromise();```. If the observable is a stream, then ```.toPromise();``` is never going to return, and if its not, might as well use promises from the beginning.

Comment: @Andreas Of course you wouldn't import RxJS only to use `.toPromise()` but you mentioned you're using Angular and RxJS 5 is one of its required dependencies already.

Comment: @martin I meant the ```import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'``` :) But then again, that's not the entire library, so my bad!